# How to troubleshoot my routing which return 404 on spring cloud gateway?

Tags: spring, routes, spring-cloud-gateway

I have already read the tutorial on [baeldung spring cloud gateway](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway) and [baeldung routing predicate factory](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-routing-predicate-factories). I also already have downloaded the [example](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-cloud-modules/spring-cloud-gateway) and tried to implement the gateway filter and predicate. But it seems not getting executed/ applied.

The routes config seems properly injected, but why my route return 404?
[image]

Here is my objective (additional question):

1. routing from the base-path (servlet context path).
2. get GatewayFilter and y executed to modify incoming requests.
3. create and apply GatewayFilter.
4. getting clue from logging as described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#log-levels).

Here is the bean trying to route

```java
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, ModifyRequestGatewayFilterFactory modifyRequest,
                                           ChainRequestGatewayFilterFactory chainRequest) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("catalogue", r -> r
                        .path("/baz")
                        .filters(f -> {
                            return f.filter(modifyRequest.apply(new ModifyRequestGatewayFilterFactory.Config()));
                        })
                        .uri("http://baeldung.com"))
                .route("myOtherID", r -> r.path("/bar")
                        .filters(f -> f.filter(chainRequest.apply(new ChainRequestGatewayFilterFactory.Config())))
                        .uri("http://google.com"))
                .build();
    }
```

which does not work at all, the filter factory is similar and taken from com/baeldung/springcloudgateway/customfilters/gatewayapp/filters/factories

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - ChainRequest
        - ModifyRequest
#        - customGlobalPostFilter
      routes:
        - id: baeldungs
          uri: https://baeldung.com
          predicates:
            - Path=/baeldung/
        - id: foo
          uri: localhost:9999
          filters:
            - ChainRequest
            - ModifyRequest
          predicates:
            - Path=/foo/

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Here is pom.xml, I also have parent pom which have spring-boot-starter-web dependency.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```